# What is the order of catch block execution when multiple exceptions are thrown and why?

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch, throw

In the following code, the function throws two exceptions in one statement. Now, why is the int catch block handles the exception and not the other block?
Is this always the case that the last exception is the one that gets handled?

```
    try
    {
        quotient = safe_divide(numerator , denominator);
    }
    catch(DivideByZero)
    {
        cout << "Error: Division by zero!\n"
            << "Program aborting.\n";
        system("pause");
    }

    catch (int )
    {
        cout << "got you " << endl;
        cout << "top : " << numerator << endl;

        system("Pause");
        exit(0);
    }

    double safe_divide(int top, int bottom) throw(DivideByZero,int)
    {
        if(bottom == 0)
            throw (DivideByZero(),top);

        return top/static_cast<double>(bottom);
    }
```

Comment: *In the following code, the function throws two exceptions in one statement.* - it does not, only `top` is thrown, while result of `DivideByZero()` is discarded due to comma operator

Comment: did you mean something like `throw DivideByZero(top);` instead ?

Answer (score 7):

This expression `throw (DivideByZero(),top);` does not throw two exceptions (which is impossible). It only throws one exception, which is an `int`.

Here the `,` is an example of the rarely used *comma operator*. This operator takes two expressions, evaluates the first, throws that result away, then evaluates the second and returns the value of that.

In practical terms the comma operator is only used when the first expression has some side effect. Since that is not the case here, your code could be simplified to `throw top;` which makes it clear that an `int` is being thrown.

Comment: A comment about using `-Wall` would improve this answer.